# Python DOCTYPE Syntax Error

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/python

# Import modules for CGI handling 
import cgi, cgitb 

# Create instance of FieldStorage 
form = cgi.FieldStorage()

name = form.getvalue('name')
age = int(form.getvalue('age')) + 1
print "Content-type: text/html"
print
print "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">"
print "<html>"
print "<head><title></title></head>"
print "<body>"
print "<p> Hello, %s</p>" % (name)
print "<p> Next year, you will be %s years old.</p>" % age
print "</body>"
print "</html>"
```

Whenever I write the DOCTYPE down, I get an Invalid Syntax error. Don't know what the problem is. Help would be appreciated since I'm new to python. Thank you!

Comment: You get an error when you print "!DOCTYP...."? You might want to separate those with commas, or escape out of the quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your quotes are conflicting (notice how the syntax highlighting breaks after that line).

Either use single quotes:

```
print '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" '
       '"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'
```

Or triple quote it:

```
print """<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Use different quotes:

```
print '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'
```

Print statement sees the quotes in the middle as ending quotes. You need to escape out of quotes by using /" or using different quotes.

```
print '<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN\"\"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd\">'
```

Answer (score 1):

You have double-quoted a string that already contains a double-quote. Python thinks your string ends after `PUBLIC`, and the next thing appears to be a minus sign followed by a division sign, which is an error. On top of that, you have broken the string into two lines without any continuation characters, which won't work. Use triple-quotes to allow a string to continue from one line to the next (this will also resolve your problem with the embedded `"` characters).

```
 print '''<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">'''
```

Answer (score 1):

For those kind of "long-multiline-text" you might prefer using the [triple quotes](http://docs.python.org/release/1.4/tut/node70.html) (`"""`).

Coupled with the [`format`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) string method available on any decently recent version of Python, you get the *poor's man* template engine:

```
tmpl = """Content-type: text/html

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN
       "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
<head><title></title></head>
<body>
<p> Hello, {name}</p>
<p> Next year, you will be {age} years old.</p>
</body>
</html>
"""

print tmpl.format(name='Sylvain', age=40)
```